# How can i get all the results with different filter criteria using dplyr or loop in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have come up with a question when I trying to get all the output data.frame under different filter criteria (by using `dplyr::filter` method) using R.
Here is my data for illustrating:

```
df <- tibble(a = rnorm(10),b = rnorm(10),c = rnorm(10))
```

as you can see, df has 3 columns. I want to put different filter method on each column and get all the results of the number of row.
For example,

```
df_number1 <- df %>% filter(a > 0.2, b >0.7, c>=0.5) %>% nrow()
```

I also want to know

```
df_number2 <- df %>% filter(a > 0.2, b >0.7, c<0.5) %>% nrow()
```

So there are 2^3 = 8 kinds of different situations, how can I get the results at once?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: use mutate instead of filter

Answer (score 0):

First we can use some `ifelse` statements to create some descriptive strings specifying the condition, this is only for better descriptions in the output. Then use `table` to "count" the occurrence of each string. Finally, change the `table` output to a dataframe for better visualisation.

In this way, you can see a complete picture of counts with different condition combinations.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12)
df <- tibble(a = rnorm(10),b = rnorm(10),c = rnorm(10))

df %>% mutate(a = ifelse(a > 0.2, "a > 0.2", "a <= 0.2"),
              b = ifelse(b > 0.7, "b > 0.7", "b <= 0.7"),
              c = ifelse(c >= 0.5, "c >= 0.5", "c < 0.5")) %>% 
  table() %>% 
  as.data.frame()

        a        b        c Freq
1 a <= 0.2 b <= 0.7  c < 0.5    6
2  a > 0.2 b <= 0.7  c < 0.5    1
3 a <= 0.2  b > 0.7  c < 0.5    1
4  a > 0.2  b > 0.7  c < 0.5    0
5 a <= 0.2 b <= 0.7 c >= 0.5    1
6  a > 0.2 b <= 0.7 c >= 0.5    1
7 a <= 0.2  b > 0.7 c >= 0.5    0
8  a > 0.2  b > 0.7 c >= 0.5    0
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(-1.48056759491936, 1.57716947155863, -0.956744479084269, 
-0.920005247558641, -1.99764209693134, -0.27229604424923, -0.315348711467784, 
-0.628255236517538, -0.106463884872094, 0.428014802202354), b = c(-0.777719582147445, 
-1.29388229761362, -0.779566508059429, 0.0119517585652984, -0.152416237822168, 
-0.703464254478642, 1.18887915627567, 0.340512270849188, 0.506968172259166, 
-0.293305149081411), c = c(0.223641415376273, 2.00720145694544, 
1.01197911806715, -0.302459245168265, -1.02524483901366, -0.267384829994282, 
-0.199105661114762, 0.131122595424375, 0.145799895543701, 0.362064721117229
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! However, I come up with another question. what if the filter method is not that exclude each other? for example, filter method for (colomn a) is a <=0.2 or a <= 0.3(but not a > 0.2). As you can see, the number 0.15 meets all the 2 kinds filter methods.

Comment: @TimmothyTung I'm not sure what do you what to achieve. In `mutate`, you can just change the criteria to whatever you want